# sonata_type_date_picker not working with multiple language

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I have configure sonata admin with two languages.
**`1. EN , 2. AR`**
Default language is **EN**.

`Question`

how can we disable language for `sonata_type_date_picker` to use only default `en` language for datepicker ?

it works perfect when date value is empty, when i select a date and update its record it convert into Arabic language

I've render field with `configureFormFields` like.

```
->add( 'publicationDateStart', 'sonata_type_date_picker')
```

`Symfony 2.8.3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using [Sonata Intl Bundle](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataIntlBundle) For locale.

Fixed this issue by adding below line to MyCusomBundle Admin Class.

**`\Locale::setDefault( 'en' );`**

Above code set configured locale in admin locally.